# Newbie Neo4j issue about Match/with clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

So Imagine that in my you have a relationship `[event] --> [person]`
and this event can have many relationships to the same person. For example:

```
   /-----------\
  /---------v   v
event----->[person]
  \---------^
```

In this case we have an event have 3 relations with this [person] node.
(There may be many occurrences of this)

**My problem** is only selecting the ones with more then x of the same relationship.

Right now I have the query.

```
MATCH (e:Event)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(f:Follows { name: "ExamplePerson"})
with e, count(r) as alias
where alias > 3
return e, alias
```

But this is returns total relationships for example:

```
   /------------- \
  /------------v   v
event----->[person1]
  \---------^
   \---------->[person2]
```

= 4 instead of 3.
 I have also tried the following:

```
MATCH (e:Event)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(f:Follows { name: "ExamplePerson"})
with e, count((e:Event)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(f:Follows { name: "ExamplePerson"})) as alias
where alias > 3
return e, alias
```

Without success what  am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first query should not have returned anything at all, since it is testing for "> 3" rather than ">= 3". In fact, when I try to reproduce what you have described, I do get no results. And, when I change the test to ">= 3", I see a result with the expected `alias` of `3`. Can you create a console (at http://console.neo4j.org/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Actually my first query works. I just figured out that it was a data problem. Some of the data somehow got corrupted. So I just reinserted the data from a backup and everything works.

Comment: OK, but it does not work when using the data you showed in your question...

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. I am sorry I forget an extra line

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, 3 is not > 3.

Comment: OK, now it should work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping for the same person, such as this change into your 1st attempt:

```
MATCH (e:Event)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(f:Follows { name: "ExamplePerson"})
with e, f, count(r) as alias
where alias > 3
return e, f, alias
```